# Как переписать код программы используя процедуры?

Tags: pascal

Программа работает отлично, но код  должен состоять из процедур.

```
program massiv;
uses crt;
var a,b,c:array [1..10, 1..10] of integer;
    n,m,i,j,k,x:integer;
    f1:text;
begin
Clrscr;
Assign (f1, '1.txt');
reset(f1);
n:=10;
m:=6;
writeln('исходная матрица  ' );
for i:= 1 to n do
 begin
  for j:= 1 to m do
   begin
    read (f1, a[i,j]);
    write(a[i,j]:4);
   end;
  writeln;
 end;
close(f1);
readln;
m:=m-1;
writeln('удалили последний столбец ');
for i:=1 to n do
 begin
  for j:= 1 to m do
  write(a[i,j]:4);
  writeln;
 end;
readln;
for i:=1 to m do
for j:=1 to n do
b[i,j]:=a[j,i];
writeln('транспонированная матрица  ');
for i:=1 to m do
 begin
  for j:=1 to n do
  write (b[i,j]:4);
  writeln;
 end;
readln;
for k:=1 to 5 do
for j:=1 to 6 do
   begin
     c[k,j]:=0;
     for i:=1 to 10 do
       begin
         c[k,j]:=c[k,j]+b[k,i]*a[i,j];
       end;
   end;
writeln('Умножение матрицы А на матрицу At:');
for i:=1 to 5 do
 begin
  for j:=1 to 6 do
  write(c[i,j]:7);
  writeln;
 end;
readln;
x:=6;
writeln('Матрица для обратной ');
for i:=1 to 5 do
begin
for j:=1 to 5 do

write (c[i,j]:7);
writeln;
end;
readln;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Процедуры нужны для повышения структурированности программ и избавления от ненужного копирования. У вас в коде достаточно очевидно выявить логические блоки:

- создание и заполнение исходной матрицы
- транспонирование матрицы
- перемножение матриц
- ...

Ваша задача - вынести часть этого кода в процедуры согласно правилам языка.